# Как разместиить view друг под другом в UIScrollView

Tags: swift, scrollview

Нужно разместить 500 `View` в `ScrolView`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var newView: UIView!


    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView! {
        didSet {
            scrollView.delegate = self

        }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        newView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        newView.layer.shadowRadius = 20.0
        newView.layer.shadowOpacity = 4

        newView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor


    }
}
```

Comment: а код этот весь зачем тут?

Answer (score 1):

Тебе нужен цикл во первых, я бы сделал что то вроде этого

```
 var newView: UIView!

 for i in 1 ..< 500{
        newView =  UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: CGFloat(i) * self.newView.frame.size.height, width: self.newView.frame.size.width, height: self.newView.frame.size.height))            
        newView.tag = i

scrollView.addSubview(newView)
    }

scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollView.frame.size.width, height: scrollView.frame.size.height * CGFloat(500))
```

ну естественно нужно дорабатывать, думаю с этого цикла можно начинать.

Comment: Спасибо! Работает! Нужно только вью создавать внутри цикла

Comment: @AlexVolkov Рад был помочь.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in 0 ..< 500 {

        let newView =  UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: CGFloat(i) * 50, width: 50, height: 50))


        newView.tag = i

        newView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor

        newView.layer.cornerRadius = 15

        newView.layer.shadowRadius = 20.0
        newView.layer.shadowOpacity = 4
        newView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor

        scrollView.addSubview(newView)
                }

          scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollView.frame.size.width, height: scrollView.frame.size.height * CGFloat(500))
```